# Htaccess : making Fake folder to get accessible/

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have created the folder `http://domain.com/sport/`

What I need it to do now is show contents of `http://domain.com/sport/index.php` whenever I access `http://domain.com/sport/anything/anything/`.

Right now its showing contents of `http://livesports.pw/index.php`

I tried code below, but it's not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

**Note** : The folder **/sport/** is just an example folder. It can vary. Even if more folder are created, it 
must work even for the new ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?)/?$ /$1/index.php [L]
```

Comment: i want domain.com/anything to point to domain.com/index.php as well

Comment: could it be used like this `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*?)/?$ /$1/index.php [L]` ?